# How to get the highest value in a column depending on three other columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

The aim is to get the highest educational value between two partners in a household by disregarding the educational level of the children. The first column `hhid` is the household number id, the second column is the individuals `id`. The third column `relation` is the relationship between the individuals in a household: `1` refers to the head of the household, `2` refers to the partner and `3` refers to the children. The fourth column refers to the educational level of these individuals.

The fifth column is the column i would like to get using a code. The aim is to only focus on the highest educational level within a household but only between parents. I usually use `pmax` to get the highest value between two columns, and `group_by` to aggregate individuals under a group like a household, but these two commands to not seem to work in this case. Could someone help please?

```
 hhid id     relation    education    highest_education
    
  1     1        1         3                 3
  1     2        2         2                 3
  1     3        3         5                 3
  2     4        1         4                 4
  2     5        2         2                 4
  3     6        1         1                 2
  3     7        2         2                 2
  4     8        1         1                 3
  4     9        2         3                 3
  4    10        3         4                 3
```

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(hhid = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), id = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), relation = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 3), education = c(3, 2, 5, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(hhid) %>% 
  mutate(highest_education = max(education[relation %in% c(1, 2)])) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>     hhid    id relation education highest_education
#>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>             <dbl>
#>  1     1     1        1         3                 3
#>  2     1     2        2         2                 3
#>  3     1     3        3         5                 3
#>  4     2     4        1         4                 4
#>  5     2     5        2         2                 4
#>  6     3     6        1         1                 2
#>  7     3     7        2         2                 2
#>  8     4     8        1         1                 3
#>  9     4     9        2         3                 3
#> 10     4    10        3         4                 3
```